# Problems with Q-learn not learning to play game

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I been trying to use Q-learn to teach an agent to play a snake game. When training I see that loss gets lower and lower but when I try to have the agent play the game after training around 8hours on a MBP it doesn't seem to grasp anything of the game.

Q-learn: https://github.com/hugocool24/Snake-qlearn/blob/master/qlearn.py
The game: https://github.com/hugocool24/Snake-qlearn/blob/master/snake.py

Any kind of feedback will be appreciated :)

Comment: You should monitor other things besides the loss, such as game length, number of points, etc. Supposing your implementation is correct, the most likely mistake is in your reward function

Comment: Alright do you think I should have an more advanced reward function? I will try to add game length as reward as well :)

Comment: I didn't read your code, to be honest, and I cannot say what works (because I don't know). There is a lot of room for experimentation here, have fun!